# Singing in tune translation help

Tags: translation, mandarin

I sang Chinese karaoke last night... went alright... but couldn't sing in tune. I wanted to express this to my Chinese friends.... so I wanted to learn phrases/words related to singing and music, namely:

How do you say "Sing in tune", or perhaps "carry a melody"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Out of tune

- **跑调/走调/走音**——年纪大了，王菲唱歌也开始走音了。要不我们就叫她跑调天后吧。
- **音调不准**——这架钢琴音调不准，和你唱歌一样。
- **不着调/不合调**——你唱歌挺不着调的。
- **音准差**——你唱歌音准太差了。`音准` is a professional term.

The phrase 不着调 has later taken a metaphoric meaning to describe an erratic person or deed. 你这人挺不着调的，办事也不着调。

### In tune

Just take the negative forms and you're set:

- **着调/合调**——你唱歌还挺合调的。
- **音调准**——你唱歌音调很准。
- **音准很好/不错**——这架钢琴音准很好，你唱歌音准不错。This is how a music teacher praises you.

Answer (score 1):

> sing in [out of] tune
>
> 唱得合调子[不合调子]

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you cannot follow BOTH the tone of the music AND the Mandarin tone strictly at the SAME time, I'd say it's *normal*.

Simply sing the lyrics by glide, vowel and the *musical* tone.  It will be fine.